# Как правильно замапить два класса с помощью ManyToMany

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Есть два класса `Book` и `Author` и есть третий класс для их связи `Book_author(id, id-author, id-book)`.

как правильно замапить связи между ними?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Book_author")

public class Book_author {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;


    @Column(name = "book_id")
    private Integer book_id;

    @Column(name = "author_id")
    private Integer author_id;

// get set
}
```

Comment: Можно по разному. Что не получается?

Comment: @RomanC именно замапить в таблице(ентити) со связями, типа автор должен иметь много книг и их (книги) я должен задать в третей таблице через форму. Я не знаю как правильно ето реализовать. По простому замапить в авторе книги а в книгах автора но надо именно через третью таблицу.

Comment: а с какой целью голосуем за переоткрытие? у кого-то созрел **новый** ответ на этот вопрос?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin переоткрыл не я а модератор. Зачем? не знаю

Answer (score 2):

Что-то типа такого у вас будет в авторской энтити

```
private Set<Book> books;

 @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "book_author", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
    })
    public Set<Book> getBooks() {
        return books;
    }
```

Что то вроде такого в книжной:

```
 private Set<Author> authors;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "books")
    public Set<Author> getAuthors() {
                    return authors;
                }
```

Дополнительная энтити как у вас, не нужна, хотя таблица с соответствующими полями, конечно же, должна быть создана

Comment: Такая реализация конечно прекрасная, по шаблону, но дело в том что надо именно в третей таблице ето зделать и замапить по id`ишникам. Возможно такое реализовать? или все же лучше так как вы зделали?    И еще вопрос почему тогда таблица нужна создана если  ее не юзать?

Comment: Так третья таблица все равно будет - не будет только третьей энтити. Таблица есть, а вот класса как у вас нет. Вам нужно начать с того, чтобы почитатькак хибер работает с manytomany

Comment: Кажись отличие наконец-то поняв. ManyToMany юзаем в том ентити с которым мы маппимся. Или или же я что-то пропустил?

Comment: Да. У нас есть две энтити - Книга и Автор с отношением ManyToMany. Для того, чтобы декларировать это отношение в JPA мы должны в первой сущности иметь коллекцию значений с аннотацией ManyToMany и во второй сущности иметь коллекцию значений с аннотацией ManyToMany. Заметьте, сущностей у нас ДВЕ. А вот таблиц в базе данных вы создадите ТРИ. Третья таблица - это book_author с  author_id и book_id. JoinTable(name = "book_author" - вот эта конструкция указывает хиберу эту вспомогательную таблицу - все остальное хибер сделает без вас - третью ЭНТИТИ как у вас создавать НЕ НАДО.

Comment: Про третью таблицу(Entity) я понял. Просто хотел убедиться в своих мыслях. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Замапить - значит ставить аннотации на поля которые вы хотите мапить. Связная таблица нужна для `@ManyToMany` отношений, и вы её не можете использовать как энтити, поскольку она создаётся автоматически и содержит только внешние ключи.

Если же вы все-таки решили использовать связную таблицу как энтити, то вам надо отказаться от `@ManyToMany`  аннотации и использовать `@ManyToOne`.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")
private Book book;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
private Author author;
```

Comment: То есть мне ну нужно к  каждой Entity добавить поле (в автора книгу и наоборот) а третья Entity (связи) мне нужна?  Мне как вариант говорили что хороший вариант через @ManyToMany зделать, как именно? и мне интересно ваша точка зрения по этому поводу, делать как вы написали или есть еще варианты?

Comment: Если хотите мою точку зрения, то я бы вообще отказался бы от ленивых коллекций. По поводу ManyToMany вам уже объяснили, незачем повторять одно и тоже миллион раз.

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду  про "отказ от ленивых коллекций"?  а какая тогда  альтернатива?

Comment: Это такие коллекции, которые не инициализируются. Альтернатива, коллекции создаёт руками.

Comment: Вы о примере мапинга ManyToMany, где юзают List'ы или Setы'?