# Не получается правильно задать отношение ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, nhibernate

У меня есть две сущности `user` и `relationship`. Две таблицы. Таблица `USER_FM`:

```
CREATE TABLE USER_FM(
USER_ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
USER_FIRST_NAME NVARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL,
USER_LAST_NAME NVARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Таблица `RELATIONSHIP`:

```
CREATE TABLE RELATIONSHIP(
RELATIONSHIP_ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ID_USER_FROM NUMBER,
CONSTRAINT RELATIONSHIP_USER_FROM_FK FOREIGN KEY (ID_USER_FROM)REFERENCES USER_FM(USER_ID),
ID_USER_TO NUMBER,
CONSTRAINT RELATIONSHIP_USER_TO_FK FOREIGN KEY (ID_USER_TO)REFERENCES USER_FM(USER_ID),
STATUS_TYPE NVARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL CHECK (STATUS_TYPE = 'never_been_friends' OR 
STATUS_TYPE = 'were_once_friends' OR STATUS_TYPE = 'request_has_been_sent' OR 
STATUS_TYPE = 'request_rejected' OR STATUS_TYPE = 'friends')
);
```

Сущность `User`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER_FM")
public class User extends IdEntity{
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private List<Relationship> statusUserFrom = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Relationship> statusUserTo = new ArrayList<>();

    public User() {
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "USER_SQ", sequenceName = "USER_FM_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "USER_SQ")
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "USER_FIRST_NAME", nullable = false)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    @Column(name = "USER_LAST_NAME", nullable = false)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Relationship.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_fm_relationship", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_user_from")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
    public List<Relationship> getStatusUserFrom() {
        return statusUserFrom;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Relationship.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_fm_relationship", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "id_user_to")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")})
    public List<Relationship> getStatusUserTo() {
        return statusUserTo;
    }
//setters
```

Сущность `Relationship`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RELATIONSHIP")
public class Relationship extends IdEntity {
    private Long id;
    private User userFrom;
    private User userTo;
    private RelationshipStatusType statusType;

    private List<User> usersFrom = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<User> usersTo = new ArrayList<>();

    public Relationship() {
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "R_SHIP_SQ", sequenceName = "RELATIONSHIP_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "R_SHIP_SQ")
    @Column(name = "RELATIONSHIP_ID")
    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "ID_USER_FROM")
    public User getUserFrom() {
        return userFrom;
    }

    @Column(name = "ID_USER_TO")
    public User getUserTo() {
        return userTo;
    }

    @Column(name = "STATUS_TYPE")
    public RelationshipStatusType getStatusType() {
        return statusType;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "statusUserFrom")
    public List<User> getUsersFrom() {
        return usersFrom;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "statusUserTo")
    public List<User> getUsersTo() {
        return usersTo;
    }
//setters
```

Пробовал всякие разные варианты для назначения параметров над свойствами списков в классе `User`, но в итоге получаю одну и ту же ошибку:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in com.findme.config.AppConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.findme.models.User, at table: RELATIONSHIP, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ID_USER_FROM)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1745)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:853)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:400)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:291)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4625)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5091)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:703)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1737)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:287)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.findme.models.User, at table: RELATIONSHIP, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ID_USER_FROM)]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:402)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1741)
    ... 59 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.findme.models.User, at table: RELATIONSHIP, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(ID_USER_FROM)]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getType(SimpleValue.java:456)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.isValid(SimpleValue.java:423)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Property.isValid(Property.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:597)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.validate(MetadataImpl.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:459)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
    ... 63 more
```

Подскажите что делаю не так и в чём проблема ? Почему не определяется тип для колонки `ID_USER_FROM` ?

Comment: В [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/index.html?overview-summary.html) есть 3 примера

Comment: Как видно из 2-го примера `targetEntity` нужно указывать тогда, когда у коллекций не указан тип. Попробуй убрать.

Comment: not a Programmer, не могли бы дать ссылку именно на примеры ?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: not a Programmer, именно по этим примерам я и делал, после чего создал вопрос тут... на данный момент решения так и нет ((

Comment: not a Programmer, у меня в таблице `RELATIONSHIP` два внешних ключа ссылающихся на один первичный ключ в таблице `USER_FM` ... по идее хибернэйт должен сам сделать третью таблицу для связи этих родительских сущностей ... я пробовал и с созданием таблицы `USER_RELATIONSHIP` и без неё, так ничего и не получается пока ... уже голова дымится

Comment: Во-первых уберите `targetEntity`, во-вторых попробуйте указать разные имена таблиц (`name` в `@JoinTable`)

Comment: not a Programmer, `targetEntity` давно уже убрал, имена таблиц разные ставил и в `JoinColumns` тоже подставлял разные колонки, короче крутил по всякому и ни как ((( Сейчас создал третью, связывающую, таблицу, точно по примеру `Vlad Mihalcea` и снова получил ошибку, но немного другую - `org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKg0ix9j8conu6qd2066qed28ay:RELATIONSHIP [RELATION_ID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (RELATIONSHIP [USER_ID,RELATION_ID])`

Comment: Возможно User является ключевым словом, попробуйте указать другое имя таблицы для класса User

Comment: not a Programmer, таблица сущности `User` называется `USER_FM`, с ключевыми словами уже сталкивался

Comment: Если создавать промежуточную таблицу, то аннотация выбрана неверно. Я где-то писал уже https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/902096/204920

Answer (score 0):

Одна из статьей, которой я когда-то пользовался - [ссылка](https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-spring-mvc-spring-security-mysql-a5d8545d837d)
`@Data` - это говорит ваше программе автосгенерировать Setters и Getters, т.е. вам не надо самому прописывать их)

Чтобы получить доступ к этому, добавьте в `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Не надо самому создавать, если Вы так сделали, sql-файлы для создания таблиц! Hibernate делает это сам.

Я примерно покажу как должны выглядить ваши entity:

`User.java`:

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Set;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_USER_FROM")
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "USER_LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "RELATIONSHIP", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "RELATIONSHIP_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
    private Set<Relationship> relationships;
}
```

`Relationship.java`:

```
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "RELATIONSHIP")
public class Relationship {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "RELATIONSHIP_ID")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_USER_FROM")
    private Long userFromId;


    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_USER_TO")
    private Long userToId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "STATUS_TYPE")
    private RelationshipStatusType statusType;
}
```

Comment: Использовать аннотацию `@Data` для сущностей крайне плохая идея!!!

Comment: @notaProgrammer чем же?

Comment: 1. метод `setId()` делать публичный не нужно; 2. Неверная реализация equals/hashCode; 3. Неверная реализация сеттеров для коллекций

Answer (score 0):

Так как в моём случае связь `ManyToMany` задаётся между сущностями одного типа `User`, то над полями `userfrom` и `userTo` в классе `Relationship` надо было применить аннотации `@ManyToOne` и `@JoinColumn(name = "ID_USER_FROM")`, чтобы указать `hibernate` связь между таблицами.

Answer (score -1):

Неправильное создание сущностей, отношение многие ко многим в любом случае подразумевает создание промежуточной таблицы, у которой всего 2 колонки это 2 внешних ключа, которые ссылаются на таблицы, которые как вы хотите имели отношение многие ко многим.

PK у такой таблицы либо нет, но тогда нужно создавать составной уникальный индекс либо указать составной PK, указываю обе колонки.

Далее если замапеная сущность нужна у обоих entity, то и аннотацию @JoinTable нужно указывать у обоих,
реверсивно той, которой у вас уже указана

Comment: fox.ontour, так что я не правильно указывал ? читал документацию и там говорится, что `hibernate` сам создаёт таблицу для связывания ... или я что-то не так понял ?

Comment: fox.ontour, и владельцем отношения у меня евляется `user`, поэтому указывать `@JoinTable` для коллекций в классе `Relationship` не надо.

Comment: окок, я так понимаю помощь не нужна

Comment: fox.ontour, конечно нужна ... я же не просто так написал этот вопрос )) если можете пояснить, каким образом решить проблему, объясните... да, и я пробовал создавать в базе промежуточную таблицу, результатом была та же ошибка